# User was removed from site collection admin

Tags: sharepoint-online, site-collection

My form is using People Picker control and event receiver to add users to a People/Group field.

There's a problem with a user. First I added him to site collection admins, then using the form above to add his account to the People/Group field. After that, his name disappear from site collection admin list.

What could be the problem with the account? or something in event receiver may cause the mistake?

By the way, it's SharePoint Online.

Comment: Im experiencing the exact thing. Did you get any clarity on this matter? I have a visual webpart that creates a web, creates groups and adds users to the groups based on peoplepicker. (sandboxed solution). /Kent

Comment: We haven't found any solution yet, not sure this problem still occurs or not, since it only happens on our client site